# ExtJS--timefield--set minValue to current UTC Hour

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a timefield for which I am trying to set a minValue of the current UTC hour, obviously so that a time that has already passed cant be selected.

I am able to get the current UTC hours using the dates getUTCHours method, like so:

```
new Date().getUTCHours(); //16
```

I ran this in the console and it works fine.

here is my timefield config

```
{
  xtype:"timefield",
  name:"TIME",
  minValue: new Date().getUTCHours(),//ignored
  maxValue:"11:59pm",
  increment:"60"
}
```

I hardcoded "16", the current UTC hour, and the timefield only showed times between 4pm to 11pm, which is correct. But with the above approach the minValue is being set to 12:00am and ignoring what the getUTCHours() method returns.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your config to something like this:

```
{
  xtype:"timefield",
  name:"TIME",
  minValue: new Date().getUTCHours(),//ignored
  minValue: '00:00',
  maxValue: '24:00',
  increment: 1,
  format: 'H:i'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, minValue needs to be a string

```
minValue: new Date().getUTCHours().toString() worked
```